# Detect if user is making a call Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, phone-call

Is there a way to detect if user clicked to call in Windows Phone?
I don't want to block, detect incoming or anything else with the call, I just want that my app knows when the user clicked to call and knows the number that he is calling.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no way** currently to detect the phone call status (or any other metadata, for that reason) for security and privacy reasons.

If you ever want to know whether your application workflow is interrupted by a call or whatnot, you can rely on the [Obscured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [Unobscured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.unobscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event handlers. You can download a ready-to-go sample [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_handle_phone_calls_and_other_interruptions_in_Windows_Phone).

Answer (score 1):

No, with the Windows Phone OS, an app can not interfere with the calling functionality. The best they can do is prompt the user to dial, to a supplied number.